# Как убрать лишнею надпись?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, gsap, scrollmagic

Нашел код для медленного скролла ( ScrollMagic ), начал его разбирать и заметил, что на экране появляется надпись - trigger 1. Как её можно убрать ?

код - [тут](https://codepen.io/thiagorossener/pen/oNNomzb)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно в самой сцене надо что-то дописать, но я не нашел инфы

```
scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: document.querySelectorAll('.img-container')[1],
        duration: 500,
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле js 27 строка надо установить

> addIndicators: false

тогда слово trigger пропадет